# FRDM-K64F OpenSDA mbed firmware install - files to big

Tags: mbed, nxp-microcontroller, orange-api

I am learning how to use the FRDM-K64F in the context of evaluating Orange France "IoT Soft box" starter kit.

I am using a Macintosh, but tried also on a Windows PC and had the same problem. I keep the board reset button pressed and then plug it into the USB port & release reset, the board shows up as "BOOTLOADER" USB drive. I did compile the "blinky" example on developer.mbed.com and copied that into the BOOTLOADER USB drive - and it works.

Unfortunately, almost everything else I try to do fails:

Whenever I try to install bigger fields I compiled (in particular the very first example provided by Orange in their kit (https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/LiveObjects-iotSoftbox-mqtt-mbed/blob/master/docs/liveobjects_starterkit_mbedOS_v1.2.pdf) I get an error message saying that there is not enough free space on the drive.

```
$ sudo mount -u -w -o sync /Volumes/BOOTLOADER ; cp -X Downloads/liveobjects-iotsoftbox-greenhouseK64F.bin /Volumes/BOOTLOADER/
cp: /Volumes/BOOTLOADER/liveobjects-iotsoftbox-greenhouseK64F.bin: No space left on device
```

but also the SDA fimrware upgrade from the mbed guide https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Firmware-FRDM-K64F

I keep getting an error message telling me that there is "not enough free space on the drive."

Several questions:
- Could this be related to me having maybe installed a wrong firmware or bootloader on the board?
- How can I verify what bootloader/firmware is installed?
- How can I know if the board is using OpenSDA mode?
- What types of files are automatically installed when they are drag-and-drop / copied into the USB BOOTLOADER filesystem - is this working only with ".bin" or also with ".zip" and others ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The FRDM board is already set in "BOOTLOADER" mode.
So you crushed the bootloader firmware when you downloaded the 'blinkly' program. Now you have to reload the bootloader firmware on your board.

Find how to do it here:

https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Firmware-FRDM-K64F

```
sudo mount -u -w -o sync /Volumes/BOOTLOADER ; cp -X <bootloader firmware > /Volumes/BOOTLOADER/
```

You can find the bootloader on the NXP website:

http://www.nxp.com/products/software-and-tools/run-time-software/kinetis-software-and-tools/ides-for-kinetis-mcus/opensda-serial-and-debug-adapter:OPENSDA?tid=vanOpenSDA#FRDM-K64F

Then restart your board in "NORMAL" mode. It must appear as MBED (instead of BOOTLOADER)

After what you can load your *.bin* file by using "drag and drop" on your board. You can also launch a hyperterminal on the COM port of the FRDM board to follow step by step your program.